# What is Trinity High Water?

Tags: elevation

This question may be off topic, in which case I apologise.

I have a problem where water level is important and I have two water levels defined, Trinity High Water and [Mean High Water springs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_high_water_spring) (MHWS). I understand what MHWS is but I don't understand what Trinity high Water is and how it relates to MHWS.

Comment: yes, this is very close to being off-topic, or perhaps I should say *"under water"* for this site. You could bring it *above board* by giving some context; how will an answer to this question will help you with your GIS?  Datums and how to deal with them in maps and spatial data are on topic.

Comment: @Matt I had the same reaction (and still do) but suspected the answers might potentially be of GIS interest.  Sure enough, @mwalker has turned up a fascinating (albeit arcane) tidbit about vertical datums.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Searching Google with "Trinity High-Water Mark" in quotes (and adding London or Thames) returns a bunch of Google Books results from the 19th century.  My favorite is [this transcript of the Reports from Committees](http://books.google.ca/books?id=YyxcAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA431&lpg=PA431&dq=%22Trinity%20High-Water%20Mark%22&source=bl&ots=3VwFG3-I-s&sig=ZjOXzBMOj-Q9sgzR_RiLzcSU9Rw&hl=en&ei=kfS2TdXxNoe8sQO35ImpAQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAjgK#v=onepage&q=%22Trinity%20High-Water%20Mark%22&f=false) for the Great Britain House of Commons:

> 5838 . Mr. Forsyth.] Is the Trinity a datum level ? -- The Trinity high-water mark is the datum. 
>  5839 . Where is it, as a fact? -- Twelve feet 6 inches above Ordnance datum.  Trinity high-water mark is one of the heights which is commonly taken by water engineers as their datum line.  The Ordnance datum is the datum taken by railway engineers, Trinity high-water mark being 12 feet 6 inches higher than the Ordnance datum, the latter being supposed to be the mean-tide level.

Apparently they had a map at the time, too, which might be on the record somewhere?

Comment: As a corollary, at that time, the Ordnance Survey used mean high water at Liverpool's Victoria dock, but in the early 20th century they moved it to Newlyn harbour in Cornwall. I can't remember off-hand what the difference is, but it is something to investigate if you're taking spot-heights from the 19th century county series or town series maps.

Comment: And a corollary to the corollary, the OS helpfully has this page that describes in much detail the differences between datums: http://benchmarks.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/pls/htmldb/f?p=111:7:1061530619354143535::NO:7::

Answer (score 2):

I suspect it is the high water mark recognised by [Trinity House](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Trinity_House) (UK Lighthouse authority, plus other hydrological functions I expect).

Answer (score 0):

Text in the [2012 Port of London Tide Tables](http://www.pla.co.uk/pdfs/hydro/PLA_2012_low.pdf) states the following:

> Trinity High Water (T.H.W.) is deemed, by the Port of London Act, 1968, to
>   be a level having a value of 11.4 feet (i.e. 3.475 metres) above
>   Ordnance Datum (Newlyn).